# My query proceeds when it should throw an error

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am trying to validate a query

The below code, should throw an error. Because VIN '2234' belongs to user with ID of 2, why it doesn't throw an error when I am trying to add this VIN to user with ID of 1?

Each car has an unique VIN and a client id. Whenever I add a service with a specific `client` the `client id` must match his VIN number.

```sql
create table client (
    id BIGSERIAL primary key,
    name VARCHAR(20)
);

create table cars (
   vin VARCHAR(20) not null unique primary key,
   fk_client BIGSERIAL unique,
   FOREIGN KEY (fk_client) references client(id)
);

create table service (
    id BIGSERIAL primary key,
    fk_client BIGSERIAL,
    fk_vin VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_client) references cars(fk_client),
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_vin) references cars(vin)
);

insert into client(name) values ('Jan');
insert into client(name) values ('John');

insert into cars (vin, fk_client) values ('223', 1);
insert into cars (vin, fk_client) values ('2234', 2);

insert into service (fk_client, fk_vin) values (1,'2234');//should throw error, because VIN 2234 doesn't belong to user with ID of 1.
```

Comment: Because `vin` is only constrained on the table `cars`. FYI, `unique, primary key` is redundant. A `primary key` is unique by definition. `fk_vin` is the child portion of the `foreign key` relationship and it is expected that there maybe many children records for a given parent key. You need to be more specific about what you are  trying to achieve in order to get a useful answer. Add your requirements as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Each car has an unique VIN and a clien id. Whenever I add a service with a `client` the client id must match his `VIN` number.

Comment: I will answer once you do as asked and add the information as update to your question.

Comment: Replace the current FK's with  a compound FK: `FOREIGN KEY(fk_client, fk_vin) references cars(fk_client, vin)`. Then you will testing against the combination not each value separately.

Comment: service vins, you can get the client from the cars table. the client in the service table is redundant.
```
create table service (
    id BIGSERIAL primary key,
    fk_vin VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_vin) references cars(vin)
);
```

Comment: @David and how do I add a user service without a client id in service?

Comment: I didn't catch it before but you made `fk_client` unique in `cars` so there can only be one `fk_client, vin` combination for any given client. In that case you don't need `fk_client` in `service` because you can get that from the `vin` in `cars`. I suspect you have not thought this data model completely through. I would spend some time on figuring out what you want to achieve and see if the table structure you have gets you there.

Answer (score 0):

When a service is for a car, we know the client, because the car row references a client row.

So, if every service is for a car, there must be no client ID in the service table.

The only reason for storing a client ID in the service table would be that there are not only services for cars, but also services for clients regardless of a car. In that case you'd either store the car ID or the client ID in the service table. What you don't want is a row with both a client and a car or neither a car nor a client. You can add a check constraint to ensure that always one of the IDs is set:

```
ALTER TABLE service
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_service_ids
CHECK ( (fk_client IS NOT NULL AND fk_vin IS NULL) OR 
        (fk_client IS NULL AND fk_vin IS NOT NULL) );
```

So, depending on what you really want, either delete the client ID from the table or add the check constraint.